# How to read a text file and plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my first time using python and matplotlib and I'd like to plot data from a CSV file.

The CSV file is in the form of:

```
10/03/2018 00:00,454.95,594.86
```

with about 4000 rows. I'd like to plot the data from the second column vs the datetime for each row and the data from the third column vs the datetime for each row, both on the same plot.

This is my code so far but it's not working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import datetime
import re
T = []
X = []
Y = []
with open('Book2.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:

        datetime_format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
        date_time_data = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],datetime_format)
        T.append(date_time_data)
        X.append(float(row[1]))
        Y.append(float(row[2]))

        plt.plot(T,X, label='second column data vs datetime')
        plt.plot(T,Y, label='third column data vs datetime')

        plt.xlabel('DateTime')
        plt.ylabel('Data')
        plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

Any help or guidance would be great. Many thanks! :)

Comment: What is your function? cannot help you without that.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have made it more clear. I just need a simple plot of the data points from the second and third columns versus the date-time. Thanks.

Comment: is it .txt file or csv file ?

Comment: It's a CSV file

Comment: @Talal see my answer hope it  will help you

Comment: Hi guys, I've tried the code you suggested but didn't work for me. I made some edits. See above.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What's your current output and what's your expected output? Your code above looks alright, so what's wrong?

Comment: Hi HS-nebula, the code is now working and plotting the output I need, however, the x-axis is only displaying the times and not both the times and dates. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to read the CSV file

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', header = None)
```

From there you can use the pandas dataframe as your input for matplot. A good tutorial can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-data-exploration-56fad95f951c)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you:

```
import csv
import numpy as np


a = []
with open('table.csv') as f:  # Let's say your data is at 'table.csv'
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f_csv:
        a.append(row)  # Get each line

b = np.array(a)  # Make it as a numpy array
c = b[:,[1,2]]  # Filter it by column

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('example.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[2]))
        y.append(float(row[3]))

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

dont forget to change the name of the file in my exemple or put the correct path if you are opening the file from different location if your file have float value change  x.append(int(row[0])) to x.append(float(row[0])) and same for y

Comment: Your conversion to `int` will fail on `row[0]` because it's a datetime, not a float or numeric-type string

Comment: true I was giving just general example since he did not give details but if the file have data wrote as he show it will fail

Comment: The question states *I would like to plot the second and third columns*, so just a simple edit and your answer should work

Comment: Hi guys, I've tried the code you suggested but didn't work for me. I made some edits in my original and question and posted the code. See above.